# Magento2: JQuery not working because of element binding after load my jQuery

Tags: magento2, jquery, knockoutjs

Many times we just need to use simple jQuery on checkout page but checkout element bind with knockout js so our jQuery does not work smoothly. So, how can we call jQuery after bind element??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below is a way to call your jQuery after bind element**

> Use below code in your jquery and it will load after binding your
> element in page.

```
function waitForElement(query, callback){
    var poops = setInterval(function(){
        if(document.querySelector(query)){
            clearInterval(poops);
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}

waitForElement(".class", function(){
    alert("element is loaded.. do stuff");
});
```

hope this helps you.